# RabbitMQ not starting "failed to create dirty scheduler thread 0"

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq, ubuntu-18.04

I tried to install zulip on a fresh vm server. Failed while trying to install rabbitmq-server. I tried to install rabbitmq-server serparatly but it fails. Error log:

> Failed to create dirty cpu scheduler thread 0

Tried to reinstall everything which leads to same error.

Server infos:

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64bit
- CPU vCores: 2
- RAM: 4 GB
- Hard disc space: 300 GB

Has anyone an idea? Thanks in advance!

Edit:

journalctl printed this:

> -- Unit rabbitmq-server.service has begun starting up.
>
> Sep 11 20:36:27 h2843730.stratoserver.net rabbitmq-server[7076]: Failed to create dirty cpu scheduler thread 13, error = 11
>
> Sep 11 20:36:27 h2843730.stratoserver.net rabbitmq-server[7076]: [1B blob data]
>
> Sep 11 20:36:42 h2843730.stratoserver.net sshd[7230]: Invalid user vagrant from 159.203.177.53 port 37198
>
> Sep 11 20:36:42 h2843730.stratoserver.net sshd[7230]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
>
> Sep 11 20:36:42 h2843730.stratoserver.net sshd[7230]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=159.203.177.53
>
> Sep 11 20:36:43 h2843730.stratoserver.net sshd[7230]: Failed password for invalid user vagrant from 159.203.177.53 port 37198 ssh2
>
> Sep 11 20:36:43 h2843730.stratoserver.net sshd[7230]: Received disconnect from 159.203.177.53 port 37198:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
>
> Sep 11 20:36:43 h2843730.stratoserver.net sshd[7230]: Disconnected from invalid user vagrant 159.203.177.53 port 37198 [preauth]

Comment: There is a chance that the `rabbitmq` user's limits are too strict. Run the `ulimit` command as the `rabbitmq` user and see what the limits are set to.

Comment: Thanks @LukeBakken! Output:
$ ulimit
unlimited

$ ulimit -a
core file size (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals (-i) 1030716
max locked memory (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files (-n) 1024
pipe size (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority (-r) 0
stack size (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes (-u) 62987
virtual memory (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks (-x) unlimited

Comment: Please see this - https://groups.google.com/d/topic/rabbitmq-users/l1DLd8-VTPc/discussion - your VM hosting service may be imposing limits.

Comment: @LukeBakken I'm sorry, I didn't reply to you. But you were right. my provider limited simoultanious processes to a very low level. Changed provider -> RabbitMQ is working and Installation of Zulip in general worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the solution was to lower the RABBITMQ_IO_THREAD_POOL_SIZE.

Of course this is not a good solution if you want the speed of rabbitmq, but for me its just an interface between 2 applications

The problem is basically that the service i'm trying to run RabbitMQ on, is restricted too much (in other words just a cheap server)

my docker-compose setup:

```
version: '2'
services:
    rabbitmq:
        image: rabbitmq:management
        ports:
        - 5672:5672
        - 15672:15672
        environment:
        - RABBITMQ_IO_THREAD_POOL_SIZE=10 # decrease #threads for server limits
```